# network manager says "device not managed"

Tags: network-manager

[image][image]I used to be able to share my network connection by editing the Auto Eth0 to share with other computers in the Ipv4 section and now I upgraded my laptop to 11.10 .

Now are there no wired connections in the network manager. When I click my connections applet at the top of the tray it also says `wired device not managed`!

when I type ifconfig -a

```
daniella@daniella-1001HA:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e6:ba:83:d6:fc  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:45 

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e6:ba:83:d6:fc  
          inet addr:169.254.13.40  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:45 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:d3:90:43:41  
          inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:d3ff:fe90:4341/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12881 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12867 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8851081 (8.8 MB)  TX bytes:2343199 (2.3 MB)
```

Comment: The following answer from a similar question resolved this issue for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/893614/321971

Comment: @EdwardMoffett thanks! Adding the empty file named "10-globally-managed-devices.conf" to the directory "/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/" fixed it for me!

Answer (score 282, accepted):

**wired device not managed**

Most probably your interface appears in /etc/network/interfaces. By default, NetworkManager does not manage interfaces that appear in /etc/network/interfaces. You can change this behaviour.

To do this - in a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

change the line *managed=false* to *managed=true*

Save, stop and start network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

---

Alternatively, you can remove the interface from /etc/network/interfaces.

backup the current interfaces file:

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network_interfaces_backup
```

Then open the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Delete everything in that file and copy and paste the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Save, stop and start network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

---

[image]

Double check in network manager (click on the indicator) that you have *Enabled Networking* ticked and you should also force deletion of old "wired connections" and selecting the new wired connection shown in the network manager indicator.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. But you also might check out wicd if you have more network troubles.  It's in the repo, but you prolly need to do `sudo service network-manager stop` for wicd to work properly

Comment: I like the "alternative" method better because it allows you to later edit the network connection from network manager's UI, to specify additional nameservers, DHCP client ID, and 802.1x security settings, etc...

Comment: Thank you! but i needed to execute <code> sudo service networking restart </code> to make your explanation work.

Comment: I tried all this, but the second option in https://askubuntu.com/a/882812/682596 is what for fixed it for me.

Comment: NetworkManager also has the option to specify `unmanaged` devices, commenting out that also works

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I had once misconfigured something in my Ubuntu system and since then I can no longer connect to any WiFi network. But now it is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, but I had to delete the `unmanaged-devices` line too in the `NetworkManager.conf` file.

Comment: The right command to restart network-manager may be `sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Answer (score 56):

Ubuntu installs a config file that sets most devices unmanaged:

`/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma
```

To disable this, You can create a blank file with the same name in `/etc`:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked for me on 18.04.

Comment: Thank you !!! I spent like two hours on this before finally finding your solution. Works as of 18.10.

Comment: Also worked for me with a Huawei modem.

Comment: This should be combined with checked answer. After doing everything above, this file was needed as well.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you thank you thank you thank you!  (As for the others: the other amply documented "solutions" didn't work, this did)

Comment: This worked with Sixfab IoT HAT for Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked on a minimal install of 20.04. LTS.

Comment: Don't forget to`sudo service network-manager restart` afterwards :) Worked on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS - I already had everything from other answers, this was the final step :-)

Comment: This seemed to have worked and I upvoted the answer, only to find out that it messed up my managed WiFi connection

Comment: This works, but surely that file is there for a reason. I wonder how Ubuntu usually "manages" wired connections. Still, this workaround has let me get networking functional in VMs on more than one occasion, so very thankful for this.

Comment: worked on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Comment: I accessed the file and commented both lines with # and worked!

Answer (score 16):

**wired device not managed**

I had the same problem with a fresh install on my Asus Eee PC 1005HA. The live environment worked with no problems, but once installed I couldn't get the connection to respond or to not read "device not managed". When I changed the text in this configuration file and restarted Network Manager everything worked!

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

for lubuntu:

```
gksudo leafpad /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Now the text editor will open. Find the line `managed=false` and replace *false* with *true* and save the file (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) and close the file.

Restart your computer or the NetworkManager service (`sudo service network-manager restart`).

Answer (score 12):

**wireless device not managed**

I've also found this issue after installing the Ubuntu 11.10 alternate version.

In my case, the `/etc/network/interfaces` was configured during installation to download new packages, and the conflict arose after the NetworkManager was set up during the first session.

The solution I've found was commenting the lines related to the wlan interface in the `/etc/network/interfaces` (in console, `sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces` or your editor of choice):

```
# The primary network interface
#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#    wpa-ssid [your_ssid]
#    wpa-psk [your_wpa_password]
```

And then, as Joseph VanPelt proposed, set `managed=false` in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and running `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: Excellent! This worked for me on an Eee PC 701.

Comment: Setting managed= is unnecessary (unless it's meant to revert a prior change).

Comment: For me, setting managed=true is what solved it eventually. It did not work with managed=false.

Answer (score 9):

**All solutions above failed.
Here is the solution for Ubuntu 19.10 on minimal install so the odds that this solution works for you are very high.**

We are going to edit a file, but you cannot jam everything on one line as this will cause an error.  Put [keyfile] on the first line, and the rest of the command on the second line.

sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf

[keyfile]

unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet

ctrl-o to save
ctrl-x to close file and nano

**Before you reboot, 
make sure the contents @ /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf are empty**

Explanation, Please Read So you don't screw up:
Network-manager presumably looks at both 10-globally-managed-devices.conf files in the two aforementioned directories.  If neither of them have [keyfile] seperated by a new line, network-manager crashes (confirmed).  If both of them have [keyfile] separated by a new line, presumably as before network-manager will crash (unconfirmed).  Presumably [keyfile] means "use this file as config" hence the aforementioned network-manager behavior.  So one of those files should be empty and the other should have [keyfile] followed by new line and the rest of the command.  So in Ubuntu the /usr/ file will always be zeroed unless possibly way back like 14.04 or earlier.  But for other distros it might be reverse where /etc/ file is zeroed and /usr/ file edited and formatted properly.

Ubuntu Jedi Master

Comment: Indeed the only solution that worked!

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I didn't check other solutions. And this one is **working fine** for me. for the second file in `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`, you can put `#` (hash/pound sign) before the lines, which will make those comments and you won't need to delete the content of that file.

Answer (score 8):

**wired device not managed**

This is a simple command which does the same as the accepted answer non-interactively.

Run this command in a Terminal to use it:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^managed=false/managed=true/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

You may have to restart the network manager afterwards with this command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 5):

Situation like this may appear, when one runs `pppoeconf` or something similar and the command overwrites the setting saved by NetworkManager. Even though the device seems to be working properly, Network Manager shows device status to be unmanaged.

If this a normal user's pc with simple network configuration like connecting via DHCP and automatic configuration, simply out comment the lines and restart network manager.

```
$ sudo restart network-manager
```

If situations other than these, please explain.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I solved it by commenting the lines where the unmanaged device was mentioned, by mac address, in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:00:26:2d:fd:5c:e0
```

changed to

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

\#[keyfile]

\#unmanaged-devices=mac:00:26:2d:fd:5c:e0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to manage network connections. You either have to do everything thru the network manager and remove everything Except the Loopback entry in /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

or totally remove the network manager thru the package manager or terminal and use the /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/resolve.conf file to control your connections. If not you will see the error you are getting. Even with static IP I've found that the network manager makes things easy and you can configure your IPV4 connections thru the menu.

Comment: please put all of that answer into a newbie answer and I dont get any of it :( I just want it to work nothing works!

Comment: there is no Auto eth0 in the menu its blank! how can I edit anything if it isnt there! I need a useful answer!

Answer (score 1):

**wireless device not managed**

This is because the alternate images were for a period of time, configuring the wireless networks in */etc/network/interfaces*; which causes NetworkManager to, on purpose, ignore the interface and consider them online.

A good solution if you want to simply use your wireless connection (or wired) with DHCP is to comment out these settings in */etc/network/interfaces* for all interfaces except **lo**, and reboot your system or restart NetworkManager like so:

> sudo restart network-manager

Of course, this means you will need to enter your wireless settings into NetworkManager (password, etc) after clicking on the right item from the applet menu.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a non-default answer, this can also happen if your computer has a hardware ON/OFF switch for the Wi-Fi interface. If you have such a "killswitch", ensure that you haven't accidentally turned the interface off

Answer (score 0):

In 11.10 you can go to System Settings and you should see a Network Icon. Run that utility and you should see tabs for your network devices, wired and wireless. Each tab has a slider that allows you to switch the device off. Or in your case switch eth0 or wired connection 1, as it is now called, on. May be. At least check that it not switched to off.

regards.

Comment: sorry but its a no go, there is no slider. I suggest you look at my screenshot. no slider there and I repeat there is nothing in the wired connections tab in my network manager. :(