# Problem with network - Wireless network working, but wired isn't

Tags: 11.10, networking, connection, sharing, ethernet

I have 2 networks connected to my computer.
The wireless connection, that I use for connecting to the internet, and a wired connection that I use for a LAN (eth0), that I also use to share my computer's internet connection via. (This goes to a ubuntu server, an xbox and a laptop running mac (Not sure if this makes any difference!))

I have never had any problems with the setup or connection sharing before today.
It started to continuously connect and disconnect to the wired network, not effecting the wireless connection.
Any help fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Also, not sure if it will help fix the problem, but here is the `ifconfig` information;

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:68:51:38:71  
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:68ff:fe51:3871/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:307663 (307.6 KB)
          Interrupt:43 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:60:b3:eb:9c:4e  
          inet addr:192.168.0.203  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::260:b3ff:feeb:9c4e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9058 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9780 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4498374 (4.4 MB)  TX bytes:1282373 (1.2 MB)
```

Results of `ls -lrt /var/log`;

```
total 29924
drwxr-x--- 2 jetty             adm     4096 2010-07-20 22:58 jetty
drwxr-xr-x 2 speech-dispatcher root    4096 2011-01-11 16:06 speech-dispatcher
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-04-12 10:22 unattended-upgrades
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-04-18 18:36 apparmor
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-04-25 23:52 fsck
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm       31 2011-04-25 23:52 boot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root       0 2011-04-25 23:52 pycentral.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   48382 2011-04-25 23:53 bootstrap.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm        0 2011-08-18 14:49 ufw.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm        0 2011-08-18 14:49 mail.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-08-18 14:49 news
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm        0 2011-08-18 14:49 mail.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  101443 2011-08-18 15:37 Xorg.failsafe.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   16888 2011-08-19 17:08 jockey.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    6223 2011-08-26 18:59 alternatives.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  115067 2011-08-29 22:32 dpkg.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    1684 2011-09-01 08:53 pm-powersave.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    2173 2011-09-13 00:02 pm-suspend.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:28 Xorg.2.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:28 Xorg.3.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:28 Xorg.4.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:28 Xorg.5.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:29 Xorg.2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:29 Xorg.3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:29 Xorg.4.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    7271 2011-09-17 12:29 Xorg.5.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     694 2011-09-26 11:55 alternatives.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   10622 2011-09-26 11:55 dpkg.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    2257 2011-10-01 09:53 pm-powersave.log.2.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root              utmp     149 2011-10-01 09:53 btmp.1.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp   11908 2011-10-01 09:53 wtmp.1.gz
-rw-rw---- 1 root              utmp     384 2011-10-02 18:15 btmp.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    5213 2011-10-11 21:04 pm-suspend.log.1
drwxrwx--T 2 root              gdm     4096 2011-10-14 19:07 gdm
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm      314 2011-10-15 02:54 apport.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    2827 2011-10-15 03:15 fontconfig.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   32032 2011-10-15 03:24 faillog
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm        0 2011-10-15 03:24 apport.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-10-15 03:26 installer
drwxr-xr-x 3 root              root    4096 2011-10-15 03:35 dist-upgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   53608 2011-10-15 04:14 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   850716 2011-10-23 13:56 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     6509 2011-10-23 14:17 auth.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root 1921821 2011-10-25 16:53 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     4824 2011-10-30 01:17 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  3258932 2011-10-30 01:26 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    6933 2011-11-01 19:11 Xorg.1.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  245934 2011-11-02 21:02 pm-powersave.log.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp  401664 2011-11-02 21:02 wtmp.1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-11-02 21:26 apt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-11-02 21:26 ConsoleKit
-rw-rw---- 1 root              utmp       0 2011-11-02 21:26 btmp
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     3698 2011-11-06 19:17 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    69516 2011-11-06 19:40 syslog.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  1436902 2011-11-06 19:40 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    24744 2011-11-07 10:54 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    8368 2011-11-07 11:47 pm-suspend.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   328206 2011-11-08 12:40 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   199507 2011-11-10 12:32 syslog.4.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-11-11 21:25 lightdm
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    29968 2011-11-11 21:36 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    24734 2011-11-12 14:10 syslog.2.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp  292292 2011-11-12 19:12 lastlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    6933 2011-11-12 23:01 Xorg.1.log
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm    15597 2011-11-12 23:03 dmesg.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   41505 2011-11-13 01:03 alternatives.log
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm    15540 2011-11-13 01:26 dmesg.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    64541 2011-11-13 01:31 auth.log.1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 2011-11-13 01:32 cups
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  107678 2011-11-13 01:32 jockey.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root       0 2011-11-13 01:32 jockey.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  8895918 2011-11-13 01:32 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  7876245 2011-11-13 01:32 kern.log.1
drwxr-xr-x 3 root              root    4096 2011-11-13 01:32 samba
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  297066 2011-11-13 01:32 dpkg.log
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm    14913 2011-11-13 01:34 dmesg.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm    15332 2011-11-13 02:56 dmesg.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm    66791 2011-11-13 13:29 dmesg.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   57706 2011-11-13 13:34 Xorg.0.log.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     855 2011-11-13 13:36 boot.log
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm    61037 2011-11-13 13:36 dmesg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  347684 2011-11-13 13:36 udev
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  105706 2011-11-13 13:36 pm-powersave.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    10133 2011-11-13 13:37 auth.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   56540 2011-11-13 13:40 Xorg.0.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp  155136 2011-11-13 13:47 wtmp
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   422140 2011-11-13 13:47 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  2461489 2011-11-13 13:47 syslog
```

Results of `netstat -rn`;

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.42.43.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Results of `ping -c 3 -I eth0 10.42.43.77`;

(10.42.43.77 being the IP address of the Ubuntu server.)

```
PING 10.42.43.77 (10.42.43.77) from 10.42.43.1 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.42.43.77: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=7.17 ms

--- 10.42.43.77 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 1 received, 66% packet loss, time 2009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.172/7.172/7.172/0.000 ms
```

Comment: Did you just upgrade to 11.10 on the affected system?

Comment: Unplug the wired connection, wait a while (minutes), then plug the cable back in, wait 10 seconds, and type `ls -lrt /var/log`. This will show which log files have been modified recently. The last several lines of each will contain hints. 

Also, I'd like to see the output of `netstat -rn` and `ping -c 3 -I eth0 <IP addr of ubuntiu server>`. I just noticed that there's no IP addr associated with `eth0`, how do assign it?

Comment: I just noticed that there's no IP addr associated with eth0, how do **you** assign it?

Comment: Experiment with making your wired connection (eth0) a managed connection as per my answer here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-wired-device-not-managed/71205#71205

Comment: @fossfreedom I've tried everything in that thread with no luck.

Comment: ok - update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: 1 of 3 ping responses cries out for further investigation. try `ping -q -c 1000 -I eth0 10.42.43.77` and inspect your physical connections.

I had hoped you would look at the `ls -lrt /var/log` output, notice that `wtmp`, `kern.log`, and `syslog` were modified most recently (at 13:47), and look at the last 50 or so lines of each (well, not `wtmp`, it's binary accounting data).

Another way to populate the logs with interesting information is `sudo ifconfig eth0 down;sleep 60;sudo ifconfig eth0 up;sleep 10;dmesg | tail -n 20; ls -rlt /var/log |tail -n 5` and look at logs modified recently.

Comment: Looking at the `ifconfig eth0` output: `RX packets:0` and `TX packets:1443`, `RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:307663 (307.6 KB)` and the `ping` stats, makes me suspect your ethernet cable, or the connectors at either end.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that bug with Avahi. I can't find it at the moment, but it is to do with IPv6. Tries to use the same resource for both, or something. Deactivating IPv6 should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and after much research have come to the conclusion that ubuntu doesnt like sharing a wired connection to an xbox (etc) with a wireless internet connection, but what can be done is buying a wireless routher and connecting the xbox to that via ethernet cable and wirelessly to your laptop/pc, this should work (so ive been told)