# Unable to connect to https sites with wired connection

Tags: networking, connection, https

I Have a problem only with https sites.
Trying to access for example mail.google.com, after credentials, all browsers stay there waiting for response of https://accounts.google.com
With others https I have the same problem.
The problem is present only using the wired connection. Accessing via Mobile run correctly.

Disabled ufw firewall => nothing

Reinstalled libnss3-1d => nothing

I have the same problem with Chrome,Firefox and Midori too.

I am newbie on Linux.
Thanks in advance.
Bye

Comment: Any wired connection, or you only have one to test against?

Comment: I have only one at work

Comment: But I could say that I had used Ubuntu 10.4 LTS since now at work without any problems

Comment: Newbie on linux + using 3 year old distribution makes me wonder.

Comment: well I'm newbie in using networking and system administration tools. I'm not a newbie at all 'cause I'm a developer. If you ask me to tell you what a result of all connection I could remember ifconfig -a, but for more information I'm very ignorant :-D

Comment: Try the 10.04 live CD and see if the problem goes away.  If it doesn't then policy at your workplace changed.

Comment: OK, no problem. I have two netbook. One has the 10.04 yet. I'll retry with that tomorrow.
I have a doubt that immediately after installation of Ubuntu 11.10, connections run correctly. Than after the update with more than 300MB of software the problem has appeared.

Comment: trying with Ubuntu 10.04 live on the same notebook I have the same problem. A collegue has attached his Ubuntu 11.10 on the network connector and run without any problem.
A problem of my network card?

Comment: possible duplicate of [network manager says "device not managed"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found that downloading Google Chrome ver 18 directly from Google I can see all mail in Inbox, but after a while I receive a message saying that not all data has been load due to a unstable connection.

So I don't think the problem is in https anymore.

Trying to use a company guest wifi I'm able to go on all internet site without any problem.

This is probably an issue of my network card Broadcom Nextreme 5751m Gigabit Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay ! Im not sure but it may be caused by mis-configured proxies. Have you used any proxies or vpn ?

If you use firefox and any proxy addon then check whether it is disabled or not. Addons like - autoproxy,tor button,froxy proxy,anonymox etc can cause this type of problem.

You can manually check firefox network settings by edit->preferences->advanced->connection ->settings.

It also can caused by ssh client. I dont know much about ssh though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to solve this problem using ubuntu 10.04 live, currently. I have seen that firefox connection settings says to use proxy system settings. Using "no proxy" or any other options doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Trying to connect with ssh to an site on intranet it runs correctly.