# Setting up a PPPoE internet connection in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, pppoe

I've been trying to set up my internet connection and router with Ubuntu 12.04 and I've been having some issues. I am currently trying to connect directly through my modem using the PPPoE username and password provided by my ISP. I ran `sudo pppoeconf` and input my information but was still unable to connect.

Furthermore, my computer is now unable to connect to my wired network and upon startup spends about 5 minutes configuring network options before allowing 60 seconds to complete its task and eventually booting without all networks properly configured.

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux and any beginner friendly help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am still unable to connect to the internet and I've grown to accept that Ubuntu won't successfully interface with my Japanese modem, but I was wondering if there was any way to avoid the 'configuring networks' delay on boot that I have been experiencing.

Comment: Have you tried using your (ADSL?) modem to handle PPPoE (or PPPoA) instead?

Comment: My internet connection is fiber optic and since I ran sudo pppoeconf in the terminal, my computer hasn't been able to recognize the LAN cable from my modem.

Comment: Also, I'm in Japan so my internet service is a little strange. Internet access and a modem is provided by one company while my actual ISP that provided me with a PPPoE username and password is a completely differeny entity. I don't know much about computers, but from what I understand I need to set up the PPPoE information on my PC and have internet working straight from the modem before I can setup my router.

Comment: What does Network Manager have as status, for your connection?

Comment: I went to System Settings > Network and when I click wired network it says unmanaged and gives me a hardware address.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.
Just click on the NETWORK icon on top right.
Click EDIT ......
and in that, go to DSL tab.
and click for NEW.
You will bhave 4 or more tabs.
go through each of them. and only fill the information which you know.
and in the mac address field select your own mac address.
Good Luck,.

Comment: I clicked the Network tab and found no DSL connections to edit so I created one an filled in the PPPoE information provides by my ISP. After saving the connection, however, my computer still does not recognize the presence of my LAN cable and I am unable to connect to the internet.

Comment: Delete all connections from the wired tab and edit the dsl connection you just made. 

EDIT= set it as connect automatically.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to delete the one wired connection but I changed the settings on the DSL connection but I was unable to establish the DSL connection even after rebooting. It asks for DSL authentication and the password and username my ISP provided aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at:

[network manager says “device not managed”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

Although, I am not sure this is an instant fix or anything ..

Comment: Thanks David, I followed those instructions and my system now recognizes the modem; however, I still can't connect to the internet. Should I try adding my PPPoE information to the wired network "ifupdown(eth0)"? Nevermind, it seems I can't edit that connection. Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the unfortunate experience of tinkering with pppoeconf in kubuntu in the past.

I was able to configure pppoe easily when I disabled bridge mode in my router settings. Check if bridge mode is active in your router settings and disable it and try pppoe again. Bridge mode requires you to provide a username and password everytime you attempt to connect to internet. Once I disabled bridge mode, I was easily able to connect to the internet.

I am not an expert, just trying to help. Try tinkering with your router settings which must be accessible if your computer shows lan connection.