# How can I configure wired network connection on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, connection, wired

I've just installed my first linux installation on a donated computer that I plan to network and use it as a shared storage drive for all of our pictures and videos.

We have a DSL modem with both wired and wireless being available to this computer.  At this point, wireless is not an option for us to use (no antenna on the wifi card and we're not going to put money into this machine) but it was working out of the box when brought into really close range to the router.

We have ran an ethernet cable from the router to the machine.  Unity informs us that the wired connection is disconnected.. it's not!

After probing around on the internet I tried the following

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

The following was returned (from memory):

```
auth lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

So, I added an eth0 portion to that file and saved it using pico.  It then looked like:

```
auth lo
iface lo inet loopback
auth eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And ran the following commands:

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

Which just returned the command prompt, and then:

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

Which just hangs.  Then after rebooting it boots with network configuration disabled and I changed the /etc/network/interfaces file back to what it was.

Can someone help me get my wired connection working, or help me help you guys by providing you with more relevant information?

Thanks!

-Scott

Comment: After doing the commands that make it right, do `sudo update-grub`. You may need to do this.

Comment: After adding the lines back into /etc/network/interfaces I performed `sudo udpate-grub` as you said.  It completed.  I then tried the ifdown command which reports eth0 is not configured.  ifup still hangs.

Comment: After performing `sudo update-grub`, reboot.

Comment: I just re-did it again, this time letting `sudo ifup eth0` complete and it did, returning me to the command prompt.  I then did `sudo update-grub` and it completed.  I then rebooted, and was informed that ubuntu was starting without full networking.  There is now no network icon in unity.  I performed `sudo ifup eth0` and response was `ifup: eth0 already configured`.  I checked the internet connection by browsing to a web page in firefox and it is not connected.

Comment: If Unity has gone, try `unity --reset`.

Comment: Unity was not gone, simply the networking icon.  However I did run `unity --reset` and the network icon is back on there - and there's a change!  Woot!  Instead of the icon saying "Wired Network Disconnected" it now says "Wired Network device not managed".  Well, how do I manage it?  :D

Comment: Oh, no. I'll have a think...

Comment: See answer here: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

Comment: I have just tried both solutions in the most popular answer.  Neither worked.  The icon now says Wired Networks Disconnected again, and upon reboot it boots without networking.  I did do this install without an internet connection so maybe I am missing a driver or something.. although ubuntu says I'm not.  Is there a network configuration file I can view and would this be helpful?

Comment: Try mounting the drive with `smbmount`.

Comment: Did that work?!

Comment: @Scott Can you show us the outputs of `sudo lshw -C network` and `ifconfig` commands. From what you describe, it looks like the hardware might not be properly detected, which is unusual for an ethernet card. When connecting on other computers, do you have to provide credentials like username and password? Some DSL providers may require that.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check your DSL modem settings.
According to the model, type: 
`http://192.168.2.1` on your web browser and get in to the modem settings.
You should disable MAc Filtering if it is enabled.
You should enable LAN connection if it is disabled

Save the latest settings and restart DSL modem.

Finaly,
press win button on the keyboad or open the dash with mouse and write "network" 
You will see a directory picture with a cable. Click and open it.
You can see WIRED option there. Check. it must be "ON" and at the options side, choose Automatic DHCP.