# network-manager device not managed with virt-manager

Tags: network-manager, virt-manager

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.4 64 bit .

After installing virt-manager, I found my scenario would be to user bridge networking, so I managed to let my machines works with bridge interface `br0`.

From that time I lost the `network-manager`. It shows that device is not managed.

Can I bring my network interface to work in parallel with `virt-manager`?

Comment: can you see this file yet ? /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Comment: am sorry to hear that , i faced the same problem in network manager i referred to this solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that.

As they cannot be 2 GODs for this life (If you believe in GOD :P)

Only One Netwrok Manager is There:

Either network-manager or virt-manager

I can accomplish this by defining bridge in network-manager and disable bridge in virt-manager. That's the solution.

I share it for the benefit of All