# Ubunutu 14.10 not detecting wired or Wifi connection

Tags: wireless, 14.10, wired

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on a clean hard drive using a USB pen drive. After the installation I found that it was not detecting my Wifi, so I connected the LAN cable to it, but its not detecting the LAN connection either.

I checked out a few websites and tried:

1. Doing software updates by going to the Additional drivers tab with my LAN cable plugged in. It tells me 'No additional drivers available'.
2. Tried installing a Broadcom driver, but it failed with a variety of errors which I was unable to comprehend.

So, requesting your help here.

Comment: check this out http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. If you encounter incomprehensible error messages, please reproduce them here entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following and post the following output,

run iwconfig in a terminal,

```
iwconfig
```

and

```
ifconfig
```

Post the output please of the following also,

```
dmesg | grep "eth\|wlan"
```

(mods sorry, I cant comment yet)

Answer (score 0):

did you do the key combination of fn(function key)+f2 or whatever key combination that your system keyboard shows to enable wifi ?

if you done above and a option like "enable wifi" is not shown in the drop down list of network manager icon in the task bar in the top of the window then go to the system settings panel.

then choose "network" icon.then choose "wireless" from left pane. then there will be a  option in the top right corner, in front of "Wireless" label to on/off wireless.click it.it will enable wifi for you.