# Ethernet Network card BCM4401-B0 no longer recognised?

Tags: networking, broadcom, ethernet

I updated Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS and I can no longer see my network - No network devices available shows in the network drop down menu. Networking is enabled and if I choose to boot my Dell Inspiron 1300 from the network I do see some activity on the card but none in Linux. Both lights on the nic stay on permanently.

I don't know where to look for the equivalent of event viewer or similar to even start to troubleshoot, having only about two hours with the install before I updated. Original install was last October.

Any pointers on where to look in logs etc would be gratefully received.

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcomm Corporation BCM4401-B0 100base-tx [14e4:170c] (Rev 02)
Subsystem dell Device [1028:01c9]

cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost. 
blacklist b43 
blacklist b43legacy 
blacklist ssb 
blacklist bcm43xx 
blacklist brcm80211 
blacklist brcmfmac 
blacklist brcmsmac 
blacklist bcma 
blacklist b44 
install wl 
modprobe -r b43 b44 b43legacy ssb; modprobe --ignore-install wl ; modprobe --ignore-install b44
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Ubuntu is trying to report an error. /usr/share/apportcheckresume. No idea if this could be related

Comment: What `sudo modprobe b44` show? If nothing, does network work after that?

Comment: And in addition `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`

Comment: And `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: No output but the nic lights started flashing and a few seconds later I was back on. Sweet! Thanks very much. Is this likely a permanent fix?

Comment: No. It is not permanent. Please give other outputs mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: Should I run the cat ... command as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wired network driver `b44` is probably blacklisted by your wireless driver.

This should be fixed by

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

And removing `blacklist b44`, `b44` and `; modprobe --ignore-install b44`
from the last line.

The file should look this way

```
# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost. 
blacklist b43 
blacklist b43legacy 
blacklist ssb 
blacklist bcm43xx 
blacklist brcm80211 
blacklist brcmfmac 
blacklist brcmsmac 
blacklist bcma 
install wl 
modprobe -r b43 b43legacy ssb; modprobe --ignore-install wl
```

Save the file.

After that wired network should work after reboot.

**Note** In case `bcmwl-kernel-source` is upgraded, this procedure probably should be done again.

Comment: cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf    shows the output                     #  Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost.
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
blacklist b44
install wl modprobe -r b43 b44 b43legacy ssb; modprobe --ignore-install wl ; modprobe --ignore-install b44

Comment: My wireless card hasn't appeared since I wiped Windows XP and installed Ubuntu

Comment: sudo sed -i 'b44/d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
sed: can't find label for jump to `44/d'

Comment: Please add information to your original post, not in comments.

Comment: I changed the command

Comment: sudo sed -i 'blacklist b44/d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
sed: can't find label for jump to `44/d'

Comment: You do not refresh and try the wrong command. Refresh and read the answer.

Comment: The file edit and reboot now has it working. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Wired fix:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

And removing blacklist b44, b44 and ; modprobe --ignore-install b44 from the last line.

The file should look this way

```
# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost. 
blacklist b43 
blacklist b43legacy 
blacklist ssb 
blacklist bcm43xx 
blacklist brcm80211 
blacklist brcmfmac 
blacklist brcmsmac 
blacklist bcma 
install wl 
modprobe -r b43 b43legacy ssb; modprobe --ignore-install wl
```

Save the file.

After that wired network should work after reboot.

Once connected run all updates though terminal or Apps

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Wifi Fix:

```
sudo modprobe b43

dmesg |grep -e b43 -e bcma
```

Comment: What is the point of copying the existing answer? And the "Wifi Fix" section is wrong.