# Ubuntu network indicator problem

Tags: networking, network-manager, ftp, file-sharing, dsl

I am using ubuntu 14.04. at first I use a dsl connection created from network indicator-> edit Connection. Everything works fine. I can even access other people's shared folder from "ShareScanner" software.

One day I see, that I can connect internet from terminal. I got excited and install, pppoeconf by typing "sudo pppoeconf".

after installing pppoeconf with my id and password, my network indicator starts to acting weird.
[image]

Now there is no alive Ethernet connection found in my network indicator. Though there is a Ethernet card in my motherboard with a live cat4(RJ45) cable providing internet by pppoeconf.
[image]
if I go to "edit connection" I see my dsl connection but there is no connection showed in network indicator.

So I can't connect to my dsl connection from my network indicator.

The worst part is, there is a ftp server in my university. But I can't access it. Even I can't access any other ip who share their folders in the network. here is a image that my ftp(10.220.20.25) and other PC in the lan network (example 10.220.63.22) got successfully pinged. See the image, [image]

and also I can't find any PC in the ShareScanner. Sometimes I got 2-3 PC in my network but don't find the all PC's though ping shows they are online.

All of this was run very smoothly before installing pppoeconf. I don't know how to solve this problem. I use Ubuntu for my primary OS. But now I have to use it as a secondary and switch to windows which is pretty tiresome. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google saves the day again! When you installed pppoeconf, it became the manager for your ethernet connection. To give control back to the Network Manager, run

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and change the line "managed=false" to "managed=true"

After saving the file, run `sudo service network-manager restart`

Source: [network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

Comment: This works perfectly for me. A big thanks for you.