# Can't access windows pc after setting up DSL connection

Tags: networking, windows-7, network-manager, dsl

After setting up DSL connection using the following command

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

I can't access Windows PC from my networks. Before setting DSL, I could access the network, but now I can't and it shows me this message.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you setting up DSL with the same network card, as you usually access your internal network?  If so, by configuring PPPoE, you disabled your local network.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I don't have any idea regarding 'same network card' as you mentioned. Let me guess and clarify my situation -

I am using a laptop with no external network card.
I use the laptop at my home where DSL connection is used and it is working fine.
And I use the laptop at my office, where I connect to Internet

Comment: Why are you not using a router at home?  Running PPPoE on a laptop, while it has its uses, is usually not recommended for normal users.

Comment: I am using a laptop with no external network card.
I use the laptop at my home where DSL connection is used and it is working fine.
And I use the laptop at my office, where I connect to Internet using wifi and it works fine.

My office has wired TCP which obtains IP address automatically. All pcs in the office network are using Windows 7. 

The problem is -  when I connect the Ethernet cable (in the office) I can't access any windows PC, share any files. And if I don't use Wifi, I can't access Internet.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.
You have **one** network card (the thing you stick the cable in).  You have configured it as DSL, which is a very specific way of using a network connection and is totally different from using it as a normal Ethernet connection which you use at work.
You need to configure two connections for the same network card and switch between them using the Network Manager.

Even then, you are better off having a router and letting the router do the DSL connection for you.  From the perspective of your computer it would just always use Ethernet.

Comment: I don't have router. And my home Internet provider  use PPPoE method. I have no choice in this regard. I am new to Ubuntu, with almost no idea on linux. And, I don't even know - PPPoE is not recommended for normal users. I am sorry to say that. But that is the situation. Because I love linux and wanna use it.

Comment: You are mistaken.  You have a choice in this regard.  Get a router, configure it as PPPoE and use your laptop just like the office.  It will life so much easier and you will be able to connect more than one device to your home Internet connection.

However to fix your current issue: Please make two different configurations for your (single) network card and switch between them for the two different configurations.

Comment: I'll make a guide with screenshots.

Comment: Thank you.
I need the visual aid to solve this problem. And thus your screen shot guide will be nice.

Comment: I still think you should just get a router to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the "Network Connections" applications.  You get a screen like this:

[image: Network Connections]

Select "Add".  You get the following screen:

[image: Connection Type: Ethernet]

We'll start off for you "Office" connection.  The selection in the combobox will be Ethernet.  This is correct for your uses.  You get the following screen:

[image: Connection Type:]

As you can see, I named it "Office Connection".  In the Device selector, select your physical network card.  I can't say how it's named, but it will most likely look similar like mine (starting with `en`)

Click "Save".  You now get back to the original dialog, with one more entry.

Select "Add" again, but this time, select "DSL". Again click "Create..."

[image: Connection Type: DSL]

You now get a screen to configure your DSL.  As you can see, I named it "Home Connection".  I do not know what you have to enter there.  It depends on the information you got from your ISP:

[image: DSL Configuration - DSL Tab]

Click on the `Ethernet` tab, make sure you select the same device as you did in the "Office Configuration".

[image: DSL Configuration - Ethernet Tab]

Click "Save" when done.

You can remove all other configurations under "Ethernet" if you like.  When you now click on the network configuration icon in the top right part of your screen (either looks like a wifi icon, or two arrows), you will get this:

[image: Network Manager - Multiple configurations]

You can now select the one you need depending on what network you are one.

The reason is that you need to configure the same network card for different, totally incompatible use-cases.

Comment: I just hope that  the way you configured your DSL connection, using the command line, doesn't interfere with the way it normally is configured (using Network Manager, as I showed)

Comment: Apparently, you can run `sudo pppoeconf` and delete connections.  Do this first.  Hopefully that will restore your network card to "normal" operation.

Comment: I have configured two connection as you showed in the image guideline. But the problem is - my networking icon (wifi icon at the top right side) does not show these two new connections. It only shows all the Wifi networks available. It displays 'Ethernet network device not managed' as gray color [ Img: 1]. My setup connections are displayed in Img 2. I have tried to remove PPPoE by typing "sudo apt-get remove pppoeconf" and it displayed this [Img 3].  So, the bottom line is - I cant see my new connections and thus can't connect. Please click here to see the images http://goo.gl/Pgk1XL

Comment: You probably broke the managed connection by running `pppoeconf`.  I didn't tell you to remove it, I told you to run it and remove the configuration.  Let me google if we can fix this.
I see you have Wireless networks configured.  Can you get on the Internet using those?  It's going to be hard to fix this without Internet.

Comment: Try following these instructions to give control back to Network Manager (which is the GUI way of managing networks. ) http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed

Comment: Thank you. I followed your given link, applied this command - "sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf" and made the statement 'managed=true". Now my home DSL is working. And interestingly, new problem arose - it automatically disconnects in repetitive manner.  I have tried checking 'Automatically connects to this network when available' by editing the DSL under 'General' tab, but nothing happens. And interestingly - a new Ethernet option named as 'Ifupdown (enp3s0) appeared and I cant edit or delete it even.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the pppoecon thing is not interfering?  What does /etc/network/interfaces say?  I'm on my cellphone, excuse me for the short answer

Comment: When i used PPPoE conf method I had no such problem. My connection was fine. But now, it shows - ethernet network disconnected and I loose internet. Interestingly, after a while it again automatically connect me to the inernet.

Anyway,  /etc/network/interfaces says - 

"# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set enp3s0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual"

Comment: My office Ethernet connection is now working fine. No disruption. I can access windows pcs now. Thus thank you for you support :)

Comment: Ok.  Happy Ubuntuing...

Comment: About your interfaces.  Remove everything that refers to anything "dsl".  Without formatting, it is hard for me to say what is important and what not.  Try using pastebin.

Comment: Basically, the only thing you need in `/etc/network/interfaces` is `auto lo` and `iface lo inet loopback`.  Anything starting with a `#`  is a comment, so that's ignored too.

Comment: My interface shows these - '# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set enp3s0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual " please suggest me what to remove or add.

Comment: Yes, I know... Set it as I said.  I created pastebin for you: http://pastebin.com/sAR429aM

Comment: here is the screen shot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Xpv0zdw9UsNzVteElaeWJ5QWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I understood that.  Please modify in such a way that you only **keep** the **first three lines**

Comment: Owwww . Thankkkkkkkkkkkk you :) 
Now it is working excellent. (Y)
No disconnecting, no interruption .... working smoothly as water flow :)
Your code has solved the problem.
Thank you again :)

Comment: Duh.  You had two conflicting DSL configurations.  That's why.