# Adapter not showing up on Ubuntu (Netgear A6120)

Tags: wireless, 18.04, adapter, netgear

I am attempting to install drivers for my wifi adapter (Netgear Ac6120 Wifi Adapter) 

The adapter shows up when I type

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 154b:00ee PNY 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9053 NetGear, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 258a:0001

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After following these steps

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210
$ cd netgear-a6210
$ make
```

I get this error

```
export DBGFLAGS
```

*** Building driver with debug messages ***

cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/build DBGFLAGS=-DDBG SUBDIRS=/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o] Error 127
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '*module*/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [*module*/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
Makefile:59: recipe for target 'debug' failed
make: *** [debug] Error 2

What do I need to install or do to resolve this. 
Thanks

### Update 1

After installing gcc and libelf-dev i get

```
$ make
export DBGFLAGS
```

*** Building driver with debug messages ***

cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-39-generic/build DBGFLAGS=-DDBG SUBDIRS=/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
**cc1:** **error:** code model kernel does not support PIC mode
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o] Error 1
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '*module*/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [*module*/home/alexander/netgear-a6210/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic'
Makefile:59: recipe for target 'debug' failed
make: *** [debug] Error 2

### Update 2

After following the steps you mentioned i got an internal error but i wasn't able to catch what it was and it didn't show after restarting twice

 
**The wifi adapter is showing up connecting to the wifi now** 
so thank you for that  
it does take a little long to connect (about a 1 to 1 1/2 minutes ), is that just how the adapter runs on linux/ something i'll have to accept?

Comment: You need to install, at least, `gcc` and `libelf-dev` and try again.

Comment: Have you tried doing what it tells you - ie. "please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel".

Comment: I will get back to you regarding that in about 15 hours, i do not have access to the internet on my Ubuntu system at the moment

Comment: "it does take a little long to connect (about a 1 to 1 1/2 minutes ), is that just how the adapter runs on linux/ something i'll have to accept?" The original question, that your interface didn't show up, has been answered correctly, no? If it is now connecting but is slow, I think that is the subject for a new question.

Comment: haha yes the original question has been answered. Thank you for everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev build-essential
```

Then try the 'make' step again.

**EDIT**: The git repository you are using hasn’t been updated in two years. It is incompatible with kernel version 4.15 and newer.

Now let’s install a better driver. Please download this file: https://github.com/kaduke/Netgear-A6210/archive/port-to-4.15.zip

Right-click it and select ‘Extract here.’ Now back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads/Netgear-A6210-port-to-4.15
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7662u_sta
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Please tell me how it proceeds; I will probably have one final step.

Comment: Updated the main post

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Update again. .

Comment: If after you do this, you get ""Device not managed" when trying to connect to WiFi, this post solved it for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/71205/917194

Comment: This works great for me, but I keep needing to do it every time my computer turns off. Is there a solution to that? When I try to run `sudo modprobe ...` it gives me the error `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7662u_sta': Exec format error`. I then need to do `make clean` and repeat the process and it works.