# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot connect to wifi: The Wi-Fi network could not be found

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager

This has been driving me nuts. Here is a sequence of events that happened (to the best of my memory):

Wifi was working fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer. But after installing security updates (using `unattended-upgrade`), somehow the network manager could not detect any Wifi. I tried rebooting the system, then the network manager showed "device not managed" for both Ethernet and Wireless connections. According to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed) and many alike, I modified

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and changed the `managed=false` to `managed=true`, and then restarted the `network-manager` service. This did make the "device not managed" go away, and I did see the list of Wifi's in the drop-down menu of network manager. However, when I tried to connect to any one of them, the network manager just waited for a while and eventually failed to connect. It was almost as if those listed Wifi names are fake.

I then tried to use the command-line tool `nmcli` and see if there is any useful error messages. Notice that all this time `managed=true` is set. First, I ran

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

and I see a list of wifi spots that seemed pretty normal. Then I tried

```
nmcli device wifi connect <SSID> password <PASSWORD>
```

with SSID and PASSWORD being the wifi spot I'm trying to connect to. Then, after a few seconds wait, an error shows up:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found
```

**Additional Question**
Regarding the "device not managed" problem, it is strange to me that (1) it occurs at all (2) setting `managed=true` is the correct fix. I have checked the `NetworkManager.conf` files on several other 16.04 machines I have access to, and they all have `managed=false` and are still able to connect to the Internet. What's an explanation of this?

I sincerely appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after trying to configure a new wifi connection, with WPA2 with certificates and passwords and whatnot.  After failing to get this to work, I discovered that my previous connections (which I hadn't touched) also would fail to come back up.  After much mucking about, the solution was to delete the (probably misconfigured) new connection (`nmcli con del <connection-name>`). After that, the old connections started working again.