# Raspberry Pi 4B - Ubuntu 19.10 - Wired Network Unmanaged

Tags: networking, network-manager, 19.10, netplan, wired

I successfully installed `ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img`, installed the updates and the Ubuntu Desktop.

The wired network shows "Unmanaged" although I can use Firefox. Software won't install since there isn't a network present. I found a few suggestions on how to enable managed wired networking but the instructions are incomplete - like they were written for someone who knew how to perform the tasks outlined.

Is there a patch one can download to solve the problem? If not, will one be released soon?

Comment: This question is so old it might not be relevant, but have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed

Comment: 19.10 uses netplan instead of NetworkManager.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out.

To view the netplan configuration run the following commands.

```py
$cd /etc/netplan
$sudo nano 50-cloud-init.yaml
```

If the 50-cloud-init.yaml file is blank run the following commands.

```py
^X
$sudo netplan generate
$sudo netplan apply
```

Now you can edit 50-cloud-init.yaml to manage the wired network.

```py
$sudo nano 50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Here is what will be displayed in the terminal window.

```py
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

You edit 50-cloud-init.yaml by adding renderer: NetworkManager.  You have to make sure all of the indents are correct or the file won’t work.  You use the space bar and not tab to set the indents.  When you are finished 50-cloud-init.yaml will look like this.  I deleted the optional: true line.

```py
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

Now you save the edit.

```py
^X
# Save Modifed Buffer
Y
# File Name to Write: 50-cloud-init.yaml
# Press Enter Key
```

Now you apply the revised 50-cloud-init.yaml file.

```py
$sudo netplan apply
```

I rebooted the Raspberry Pi and the wired network was available to tweak.   My first exposure to Linux and Ubuntu was exactly one week ago this morning.  I am pleased that I was able to piece together online resources to figure this out.   Hopefully this update will make this task easier for others.