# Ethernet is always down after reinstalling python3

Tags: networking, ethernet, python3

**Background**

I was working on a python module and couldn't understand why it kept throwing an error, so I very intelligently decided to just uninstall then reinstall python3, [nothing](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=jU6&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALeKk00y0b3zMTRFBRRPNGEDMIx1BwpP3g%3A1606183264541&ei=YGm8X7W7IMmw5wKD7IngAg&q=I+accidentally+uninstall+python3+ubuntu&oq=I+accidentally+uninstall+python3+ubuntu&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIJCAAQyQMQFhAeOgQIABBHOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoECAAQQzoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxAzoHCAAQyQMQQzoCCAA6CAguEMcBEK8BOgUILhCxAzoICC4QsQMQgwE6CgguEMkDEEMQkwI6AgguOggILhDHARCjAjoECC4QQzoKCAAQsQMQyQMQQzoECAAQCjoHCAAQyQMQCjoFCAAQyQM6CggAEMkDEBQQhwI6BwgAEMkDEA06BAgAEA06BggAEBYQHjoICCEQFhAdEB46BAghEApKBQg8EgEzUPMcWLBbYP1caANwAngAgAHJBIgBskmSAQ0wLjE3LjE0LjYuMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi167T3iprtAhVJ2FkKHQN2AiwQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) could go wrong, right??

My apt installer still worked so after restarting I reinstalled python3-all and ubuntu-desktop. Everything seems to work fine now, but for some reason my Ethernet is always down. Wifi works perfectly fine, but my Ethernet connection no longer does. I've tried configuring it through multiple networking tools but it remains down. I've installed and reinstall python-dns and packages related to that to no avail, is there an obscure package that might of been broken or removed?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075112/1070314) answer to unmanaged ethernet connections fixed my problem, this was likely unrelated to the python uninstallation.