# After upgrade 18.04 to 20.04, Deja Dup fails to backup; something about my LAN networking is broken

Tags: networking, samba, deja-dup, lan

Deja Dup (DD) has worked w/o problem for 2+ years under Ubuntu Mate 18.04 - then I upgraded to 20.04 and DD no longer succeeds.

DD halts when "back up now", with window "Storage location not available.  Waiting for a network connection..."

DD is configured to access a local network NAS hard disk (ethernet) using smb:// protocol

When file manager Caja mounts a NAS share, it does so using smb://, and DD is configured to access that particular smb:// share.

The DD Developer/Maintainer suggests something is not set up correctly with my networking, though I can navigate my LAN and the Internet w/o problem.  I've sent him this terminal window info:

(from 'sysinfo')
Running Ubuntu Linux, the Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) release.
GNOME: 3.36.8 (Ubuntu)
Kernel version: 5.4.0-132-generic (#148-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 16:02:06 UTC 2022)
GCC: 9 (x86_64-linux-gnu)

```
 gandsnut@tinyhp:~$ nm-online
 Connecting...............    0s [offline]


  gandsnut@tinyhp:~$ ps -afe | grep -i "network"
 systemd+    1108       1  0 Nov17 ?        00:00:13 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
 root        1233       1  0 Nov17 ?        00:00:06 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 root        1254       1  0 Nov17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
 gandsnut    3638    2161  0 Nov17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-network --spawner :1.3 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
```

I don't know what to fix to make DD function again.  Suggestions?

==================
(added)   The output from the suggested command repeats 8 times...

```
gandsnut@tinyhp:~$ systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-11-17 04:00:49 CST; 2 days ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1233 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 37743)
     Memory: 12.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1233 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.7002] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.7013] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices>
Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.7049] manager: (enp2s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/De>
Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.7255] manager: (wlp1s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManage>
Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.7407] device (wlp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed',>
Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.9059] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.9096] manager: startup complete
Nov 17 04:00:50 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679250.9295] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Nov 17 04:01:01 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679261.2166] device (enp2s0): carrier: link connected
Nov 17 04:01:32 tinyhp NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1668679292.2178] agent-manager: agent[f83f5a498d6fe2d9,:1.110/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/100>
lines 1-20/20 (END)...skipping...
```

Comment: It appears that there is indeed a problem with your networking, or more specifically, with network manager, based on the output of `nm-online`.  Perhaps troubleshooting should focus on network manager. As a start, consider running the command `systemctl status NetworkManager` and copy/pasting the output into your question.

Comment: I'm glad to continue troubleshooting:  I'm unable to interpret what if anything the output from "systemctl..." is saying.  What might be the next step?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This old link provided enough assistance to get my Deja Dup backups to start working again:

[network manager says "device not managed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed)

Also, deleting the existing wired/Ethernet network connection, then re-creating it helped.  Restarting the NetworkManager application was needed.  Troubleshooting help came from the author/maintainer of Deja Dup.