# My network devices are unmanaged, but I can still connect to wifi manually using `iw`

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, thinkpad

So when I installed Ubuntu server (with i3 afterwards), I setup my wifi and everything went well. After the install, my laptop would automatically connect to my wifi.

My issue is, I cannot connect to any new wifi connections (or see them) using both TUIs and GUIs (`nmcli`, `nmtui`, gnome-network).

But when I use `iw` and `wpa_supplicant` I can both see the available wifi devices and connect to them.

`sudo iw dev wlp3s0 scan | grep -i ssid`

`wpa_passphrase SSID PASSWORD > ~/wpa_suppicant.conf`

`sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlp3s0 -c ~/wpa_supplicant.conf`

I isolated it to the fact that my Network Manager sees all my internet connections as unmanaged, this is the output of `nmcli device`:

```
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
enp0s25  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged  --         
wlp3s0   wifi      unmanaged  --
```

I tried all the solutions listed in the [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed) and none of them worked.

Output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

```
cat: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml: Permission denied
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Did you install the server edition and then, later, install a desktop environment? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: I installed the server edition, then installed i3. Which is a windows manager but I don't think it is a desktop environment. I've edited my post with the output of your command.